# Encode CryptoStream to Base64 String in Chunks in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64, chunks, cryptostream

There is a method (**Version1**) that encodes an input stream and there is a function Decrypt() that successfully decodes encoded data. But when the input data is large there could be an error **OutOfMemory** (on the line "**string textEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String (ms.ToArray())**").

**Version1**

```
    private static Stream EncryptRijndael1(byte[] key, byte[] iv, Stream plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null)
            return null;

        byte[] bytesEncrypted;

        RijndaelManaged rjndl = RijndaelManagedWithConfig(key, iv);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rjndl.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                int readed;
                while ((readed = (plainText.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
                }
            }
            string textEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            bytesEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textEncrypted);
        }
        return new MemoryStream(bytesEncrypted);
    }
```

So I modified the method to process an array part by part (chunks).
Here is **Version2**. It causes an error **"offset and length must refer to a position in the string"** in the line **Convert.ToBase64String (ms.ToArray(), offset, read)**.

**Version2**

```
    private static Stream EncryptRijndael2(byte[] key, byte[] iv, Stream plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null)
            return null;

        byte[] bytesEncrypted;

        RijndaelManaged rjndl = RijndaelManagedWithConfig(key, iv);

        string textEncrypted = String.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rjndl.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                int readed;
                int offset = 0;
                while ((readed = (plainText.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
                    textEncrypted += Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray(), offset, readed);
                    offset += readed;
                }
            }

            bytesEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textEncrypted);

        }

        return new MemoryStream(bytesEncrypted);
    }
```

Then I made **Version3**. It works without errors but the output data length now is bigger than in **Version1** having the same input data.
Decryt() function throws an error **"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."**

**Version3**

```
    private static Stream EncryptRijndael3(byte[] key, byte[] iv, Stream plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null)
            return null;

        byte[] bytesEncrypted;

        RijndaelManaged rjndl = RijndaelManagedWithConfig(key, iv);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string textEncrypted = String.Empty;
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rjndl.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
                int readed;
                while ((readed = (plainText.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
                }
             }


                byte[] buffer1 = new byte[16*1024];
                int readed1;
                using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()))
                {
                    while ((readed1 = (ms1.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length))) > 0)
                    {
                        if (readed1 < buffer1.Length)
                        {
                            var lastBuf = new List<Byte>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < readed1; i++)
                            {
                                lastBuf.Add(buffer1[i]);
                            }
                            textEncrypted += Convert.ToBase64String(lastBuf.ToArray());
                            continue;
                        }
                        textEncrypted += Convert.ToBase64String(buffer1);
                    }
                 }

            bytesEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textEncrypted);
        }

        return new MemoryStream(bytesEncrypted);
    }
```

**My RijndaelManaged**

```
 private static RijndaelManaged RijndaelManagedWithConfig(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        RijndaelManaged rjndl = new RijndaelManaged();
        rjndl.KeySize = 256;
        rjndl.BlockSize = 128;

        rjndl.Key = key;
        rjndl.IV = iv;

        rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rjndl.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        return rjndl;
    }
```

Please help me to get rid of the errors or tell me how to make the Version1 process **Convert.ToBase64String data partially**.

Comment: How large is your data? Most machines can handle encryption of a 2Gb file.

Comment: No, i try to encode 300 Mb input data

Comment: 300Mb is nothing to a modern machine (with typically 4-16Gb of RAM).

Comment: I know... I want to optimized converting to Base64String, but no one of my modification Version1 not works right.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the decision

```
         private static Stream EncryptRijndael(byte[] key, byte[] iv, Stream plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null)
            return null;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[5120 * 1024];

        RijndaelManaged rjndl = RijndaelManagedWithConfig(key, iv);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int readedBytes;
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rjndl.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                while ((readedBytes = (plainText.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                {
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, readedBytes);
                }
            }


            using (var cryptoMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()))
            {
                using (var base64MemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (ICryptoTransform transform = new ToBase64Transform())
                    {
                        using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(base64MemoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            while ((readedBytes = cryptoMemoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                cryptStream.Write(buffer, 0, readedBytes);
                            }
                            cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        }

                        return new MemoryStream(base64MemoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add comments? Why does this encrypt and encode in two separate steps? Why doesn't it call `TransformFinalBlock()` like [MS's sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform)? A code-only answer is helpful in providing a fix but it doesn't help much in understanding how your answer solves the problem. Please include descriptions.